# Closed form for $\sum_{t=0}^{n} t^2x^t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to come up with a formula for  $\Sigma_{t=0}^{n} t^2x^t$

I understand that

$$\sum_{t=0}^{n} x^t=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

I also was able to find that

$$\sum_{t=1}^{n} tx^t=\frac{1-x^n}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{nx^n}{1-x}$$

With some algebraic manipulation (multiplying the sum by $x$, then subtracting).

But what I am trying to look for does not seem to work in a similar way as the first two... is there a closed form of this?

I know that if it is an infinite series I can just take the second derivative and work from there, but this is finite so I am having trouble.

Comment: One more thing when you take the derivative be sure to adjust the index of the summation down by 1. It should look exactly as in the original problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I also was able to find that $~\displaystyle\sum_{t=1}^{n} tx^t=\frac{1-x^n}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{nx^n}{1-x}$

Very good ! Now differentiate both sides with regard to *x*, then multiply them both by *x*, and see what happens ! :-)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!  That was actually easy to follow.

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite $$A=\sum_{t=0}^{n} t^2x^t=\sum_{t=0}^{n}\Big(t(t-1)+t\Big)x^t=x^2\sum_{t=0}^{n}t(t-1)x^{t-2}+x\sum_{t=0}^{n}tx^{t-1} $$ So, $$A=x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\Big(\sum_{t=0}^{n}x^t\Big)+x\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\sum_{t=0}^{n}x^t\Big)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Similarly, if you had $t^3$ instead of $t^2$, you could use a similar trick writing $$t^3=t(t-1)(t-2)+3t(t-1)+t$$

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  It is interesting that you were able to make $t^2$ into $t(t-1)+t$.  I see the motivation once I see the expression on the right most side of the first row, but without thinking that it would have been impossible for me to think that.

Comment: You are welcome ! Remember the trick because you will probably have many opportunities to use it. The same could be done for any positive value of $k$ in $\sum_{t=0}^{n} t^k x^t$.